# Trouble with partially rendering viewport

Tags: opengl

I use the following code trying to render a partial frame of a viewport.
Start and end is a part of the frame, which is correct.

```
    glViewport(start,0,end,SAVE_HEIGHT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90.0f, 1.0f, NEAR, FAR);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The code seems out of order; I had it working before. From what I could find of sparse documentation, this seems the correct order however.

The visual output is that I do not see some parts, and the parts that are rendered do not have the correct perspective. As a note, I am rendering to the same FBO each time.

The expected output is that each time the code is called a part of the viewport is rendered to the same fbo.

My question: how can I render to an FBO partially each iteration?

Comment: So... what's the question? What is visually happening?

Comment: Updated my question, hope it makes any sense.

Comment: Yeah, that's not helping. You need to explain *exactly* what is wrong and exactly what you expect to be seeing. Be *specific*, don't speak in generalities like "some parts" or "correct perspective." Pictures help. Also, *code* helps, because there's nothing specifically wrong with the code you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for glScissor apparently.